# Pandas won't skip empty line with index_col function

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, blank-line

I experience an issue when I am using pandas in python.

I need to index my dataframe using country column. But there is an empty line after the column row which the csv file looks like this:

```
0 Televison, Physicians, and Life Expectancy
1 NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
2 country, life expectancy, people/TV, people/physician, female life expectancy, male life expectancy
3 NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN (I need to skip this line)
4 value, value, value, value, value, value, 
5 value, value, value, value, value, value, 
...
...
```

I tried to skip the empty line between header and the first actual data line like this:

```
tvdf = pd.read_csv(infile, sep=',', header=2, skiprows=[3], nrows=40, index_col='Country', skip_blank_lines=True)
```

as a return, it successfully put country column as index. however, neither skiprows nor skip_blank_lines works within index_col function. My interpretation is: If I use country column as index, it recognizes the empty line (NaN) as the first index name. And neither skiprows nor skip_blank_lines will take effect in index_col function. I tried it without index_col, it will automatically skip non value lines without any skiprows or skip_blank_lines statements.

I have been searching online with this issue, and did not found any related issues.
So in this stage, maybe I can either manipulate the cvs file and delete the empty line manually or does anyone have any experience dealing with that??

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you try `skip_blank_lines=True`, I believe it solves your problem? Please reconfirm this works on latest version of pandas (0.23+). If it still happens, please post your actual CSV input file (as well as the pandas result). Also, check [pandas known issues](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: Do you want to skip all the blank lines or only the 3rd row only
skip_blank_lines=True will skip all blank values(1&3) skip rows=[3] helps to remove the 3rd line alone

Answer (score 1):

use `skiprows=[0, 1, 3]`

```
pd.read_clipboard(
    sep=',', skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=[0, 1, 3]
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`skip_blank_lines=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) fixes this.

(no need to manually pass line-numbers of blank lines)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. blank lines still remain at the bottom, where columns say NaN and the only value is the row index

Comment: @MarkAtRamp51: I have no idea unless you post your own question with testcase. Then add a link here in comment. Also, state what version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a new dataframe - cric_scores

```
test_scores = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, '', 4, 5], 
'first_name' : ['Sachin', 'Dravid', '', 'Virat', 'Yuvraj'],
'scores' : [150, 210, '', 125, 75],
'state' : ['Mumbai', 'Karnataka','', 'Delhi', 'Punjab']})


skip = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = 'test_scores.csv', sep = ',', header = 
0)

skip
```

**OUTPUT:-**
id  first_name  scores  state
0   1.0 Sachin  150.0   Mumbai
1   2.0 Dravid  210.0   Karnataka
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   4.0 Virat   125.0   Delhi
4   5.0 Yuvraj  75.0    Punjab

ISSUE: The skip_blank_lines is not working.